# Send Push Notification to windows 8 using PHP

Tags: php, windows, push-notification

I want to send Push Notification to windows 8 using PHP. Is there any example to send it from server to Windows 8 Devices? I need also to understand the logic.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To successfully send push notifications to a windows device you need to have a Modern UI Store-App installed on the device. This app registers the device for your push messages. The push messages can then be send from your php script. It's called Windows Push Notification Service (WNS). Details including graph that show the logic can be found on Microsoft's Devloper Page.

But let me repeat this: You need to have an app deployed to the windows store in order to register your service to receive push messages.